# PHP: How to upload videos to YouTube without using a login?

Tags: php, youtube

I have a site and I want to upload videos onto YouTube without a login. Is it possibe? If yes, how can do this?

Answer (score 5):

Create an account and use its credentials all the time, for all users of your site. You simply can't upload a video without a user account 'responsible' for it. @Pekka: ask for forgiveness, not for permission? ;)
Google at least has a youtube API (with uploading capabilities and PHP examples) right here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Uploading_Videos

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to upload Video to YouTube without logging in.

That said, I wouldn't be surprised if even automated uploading *with* a login would be forbidden by YouTube's Terms and Conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that without zend client library. Its in core php (PHP4).
https://github.com/techie28/YouTubeUploadPHP.

Note: AuthSub is deprecated now.Please refer to Google Deprecated policy for details.

---

**EDIT:**
*Because `codershelpingcoders.com` now points to godaddy's parking page and the original link `zendtutorials.wordpress.com` has an empty article linking to `codershelpingcoders.com`, I found the original article via the archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20130123044500/http://codershelpingcoders.com/ and have tried to replicate it's contents in this answer for future reference (NOTE: I have no idea if this info still works).*

This tutorial describes the direct browser based upload technique using AuthSub.

`AuthSub` is the Authorization module of the YouTube that lets your application interact with the YouTube for specific purposes such as Uploading videos etc on user’s behalf.
It is same like `Auth` and a cousin of `oAuth`.
A user grants the privilege to your site application and you can do the job on his behalf as simple as that.

We will go through the way to upload a video using `AuthSub`.

It goes as follows and can be really done in following 4 simple steps:

1. To allow the application run on user behalf a user must have
   authorized it first.
   So our first step to implement is to get the app Authorized by the user.
   We do it by simply redirecting user to the authorization page the url 
   is as follows:

   ```
   $nextUrl = urlencode(‘http://www.xxxx.com’)
   $scope = urlencode(‘http://gdata.youtube.com’);

   https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest?next=’.$nextUrl.’&scope=’.$scope.’&session=1&secure=0
   ```

   The `nextUrl` here is the url of the your application where the user
   will be redirected after authorization procedure.
   `scope` is to tell the YouTube about the scope of the process which is google
   data youtube in this case.
   So if user has not authorized your app yet he must be redirected to 
   the above mentioned authorization page once the user has approved 
   your application it needs not to follow the step one ever again until 
   and unless the user revokes the access to you app from the users 
   control panel of his account.
   On successful completion of the authorization process user will be
   redirected to your application and this complete the first step of
   AuthSub.
2. If from the first step the user authenticates your application 
   YouTube will redirect him back to your application with a token in the url. 
   You are going to use this token and here is where the actual AuthSub process 
   comes into play you are going to use this token to obtain an entity called 
   `AuthSubSessionToken` which will allow you to interact your app to YouTube 
   on the user behalf who has just approved your application.
   In PHP you do it by issuing a curl request. The details are as follows:
   Issue a curl GET request to `https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubSessionToken`
   with the token you received just after the authorization step.
   Remember to turn ON the curl’s response gathering status as you gonna need that.
   If everything went well till now you would be responded from YouTube with 
   the `AuthSubSessionToken`.
   BINGO :-)
3. Now when you have received the AuthSubSessionToken you are gonna use
   that to get an upload token which will actually upload the data
   related to your video to YouTube i.e.title,description,category and
   keywords. This is kinda reverse process as in AuthSub you upload the
   data related to the video to YouTube first and then upload the video
   itself. The uploading of video data also referred as MetaData will be
   done by feeding XML to the YouTube,the xml will be:

   ```
   title goes here 
   description goes here 
   category goes here

   Keyword goes here
   ```

   and again curl has business to do you will upload this by issuing another curl call:

   ```
   url:http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken 
   headers:AuthSub token=”Your AuthSubSession token goes here” 
   GData-Version:2
   ‘X-GData-Key: key=”Your Api key goes here” 
   Content-length: length of the xml you formed above goes here
   Content-Type:application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8 
   POSTFIELDS: the xml itself that you formed
   ```
4. If the step 3 completes successfully then its time to upload the
   video actually on your successful last curl execution you will be
   reverted back by the YouTube with a url an a token.
   Now you will create a form which will have this url as its action and token
   as a hidden field something like this.
   Just select the video and click submit and your video will get uploaded.
   On successful submission you will be redirected back with `status 200`.

The github link for the Sample code is [here](https://github.com/techie28/YouTubeUploadPHP).

Comment: Because codershelpingcoders.com now points to godaddy's parking page and the original link zendtutorials.wordpress.com has an empty article linking to codershelpingcoders.com, I found the original article via the archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20130123044500/http://codershelpingcoders.com/ and have tried to replicate it's contents in this answer for future reference (NOTE: I have no idea if this info still works).